# Build machine specific property (TFS build)

Tags: build, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I'm having some problems handling build machine specific properties in my TFS 2013 build machine setup.

The path to the installation builder executable (e.g. Install Shield) is a build machine specific property - it can differ between different build machines.

How do I handle this? I cannot hard-code it into the build definition XAML and I cannot make it an argument to the build definition.

Is there any good ways to handle this and similar properties?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the path to the InstallShield in build definition, you just need to install InstallShield on each machine you want to create and update InstallShield projects. Check this [article](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/TFS-Overview.htm) for the details.

Additionally, there are two things you need to be aware of:

1. The MSBuild Platform on your Build Definition needs to be "X86", otherwise you will get the error message said InstallShield.Tasks.dll was not found .
2. Configure Build Service to run with a domain account not "NT_AUTHORITY\Network Service" account, otherwise you will get the error message said "InstallShield Licence has expired".

Please check blog for the details on how to build InstallShield in TFS build:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2014/03/04/installshield-and-team-build-on-tfs.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand the articles they describe how to build a Visual Studio solution with an InstallShield project as a part of the solution. In my setup a custom build step calls the InstallShiled executable and the path to the executable must be known.

Comment: @Helan, I got your scenario. If that case, you can put the InstallShield executable folder in a shared folder that every one has permission to access to it, and target the property to the shared folder path in the build definition. Calling InstallShield in different path on different machine is not a good idea, as you will have to determine which build agent machine you're working on first, which makes this scenario more complex.